# Bootstrap 5 DIV not sizing properly on mobile screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am very new to bootstrap 5 and website development overall. I set myself a challenge a little while ago in making a responsive website. I've created a responsive desktop one, and now wish to create it on mobile devices. So far it was going all well until my content started **appearing vertically with no padding and with 100%**. It was not responding correctly, so far this has **only happened with my footer and my contact divs**. I am not exactly sure why, this has happened as it is working fine on desktop version. I've tried moving content around with position to no success. Any help would be grand!

```css
   /*Main*/
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap');

   html, body
   {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
       overflow-x: hidden; 
       background-color: #0f2471;
       font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
      }

 /*NavBar ;*/

   #logo-space{
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
     ;
   }

   #logo-space img{
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
     position: relative;
     left: 2.5rem;
   }

   #fms-btn{
      width: 120px;
      position: relative;
      top: 1rem;
      right: 2rem;
      height: 60px;
      font-size: 1rem;
      justify-content: center;

      text-decoration: none !important; 
      background-color: #030b29;
      color: white;
    }

   .nav-bar{
       background-color: #16377e;
       position: relative;
   }
 
   #navbar-space .nav-link{
     position: relative;
     left: 4rem;
   }

   #memberCount{
    background-image: url("../img/l1.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 25%;
  }

  #why{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 220%;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  #memberCount h1{
    color: white;
    font-size: 300%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 2rem;
  }

  #memberCount h3{
    color: white;
    font-size: 180%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 2rem;
  }

  #gallery{
    width: 100%;
    height: 45%;
    background-color: white;
  }

  #gallery-title{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 220%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  #gallery-comment{
    text-align: center;

  }

  .gallery-button{
    width: 10rem;
    height: 3rem;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none !important; 
    background-color: #030b29;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    
    text-align: center;

    position: relative;
    left: 1rem;
  }

  .gallery-button:hover{
    background-color: #030b29;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
  }

  #contact{
    background-image: url("../img/l2.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 45%;

  }

 #contact-statement{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 220%;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;

    margin-top: 100px;

    position: relative;
    right: 100px;
  }

  #contact-statement-left{
    position: relative;
    right: 2rem;
    
  }

  #contact-final{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    right: 100px;
  }

  #contact-button{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #030b29;
    left: 5px;
  } 

  #footer{
    color: white;
    background-color: #16377e;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;

  }

  #footer a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #footer a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

  .gallery-redirect{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
  }


 /*responsive*/
 @media(max-width: 800px){

    body{
      margin: 0;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;

    }

    #logo-space{
      width: auto;
      height: 160px;
      position: relative;
      right: 2rem;
    }

    #fms-btn{
      width: 100px;
      height: 40px;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-decoration: none !important; 
      background-color: #030b29;
      color: white;
      padding: 0;
      position: relative;
      left: 3rem;
      top: -1rem;
    }

    #why{
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 150%;
      font-weight: bold;

      padding-bottom: 25px;
    }
    
    #memberCount{
      background-image: url("../img/l1.png");
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 15%;
    }

    #memberCount h1{
      color: white;
      padding-top: 50px;
      font-size: 150%;
    }
  
    #memberCount h3{
      color: white;
      font-size: 80%;
    }

    #gallery{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: white;
    }

    #gallery img{
      width: 150px;
      border: none;
      padding: 5px;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      bottom: 5rem;
      left: 25px;
    }
  
    #gallery-title{
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 220%;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  
    #gallery-comment{
      text-align: center;
    }
  
    .gallery-button{
      width: 12rem;
      height: 3rem;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-decoration: none !important; 
      background-color: #030b29;
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      
      text-align: center;
  
      position: relative;
      left: 1rem;
    }
    
    .gallery-redirect{
      width: 6px;
      height: 6px;
      float: left;
    }

    #footer{
      color: white;
      background-color: #16377e;
      height: auto;
      width: 100%;
    }
  
    #footer a{
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
    }

  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <!--When Site is finished, check all compats-->
  <head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <!--CSS-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b5212ab333.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--Index Stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kQtW33rZJAHjgefvhyyzcGF3C5TFyBQBA13V1RKPf4uH+bwyzQxZ6CmMZHmNBEfJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 

    <style type="text/css">

      #home-img{
            /* to remove space between images, because car image has this wave and page background would be visable */
          margin-bottom: -86px;
      }

      #home-img img{
        object-fit: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 75vh;
      }

      #about-us{
        background-image: url('./img/l3.png');
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        z-index: 2;
        /* probably padding needed */
        padding: 25vh 0;
        color: white;
        height: 75vh;
      }

      #about-title{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 45px;
      }

      #about-text{
          font-size: large;
      }

      #learn-more-btn{
        width: 15rem;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-decoration: none !important; 
        background-color: #030b29;
        color: white;
      }

      @media(max-width: 767px){
        body{
          margin: 0;
          font-size: small;
          font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;

        }

        #about-text{
          font-size: small;
          width: 15rem;
          position: relative;
          bottom: 20px;
          font-size: small;
        }

        #about-title{
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 20px;
        }

        #learn-more-btn{
          width: 5rem;
          font-size: 15px;
          text-decoration: none !important; 
          background-color: #16377e;
          color: white;
          position: relative;
          right: 1rem;
          
          text-align: center;
        }

        #redirect-symbol{
          position: relative;
          left: 3px;
        }
      }

    </style>

  </head>

  <body style="margin: 0;">
      <!--Logo Space-->
      <div id="logo-space">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <img src="img/logo.png" class="image-fluid" alt="">
          </div>
          <button id="fms-btn" type="button" class="btn  mx-4 m-3">
              <span class="text-center" style="text-decoration: none;">Head to FMS</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

    <!--Nav Bar
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#appeals" style="font-weight: bold;">FMS</a>
-->
    <div id="home">
      <nav id="navbar-space" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg nav-bar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active text-white" aria-current="page" href="#home">HOME</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#about">ABOUT US</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white " href="#divisions">DIVISIONS</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white " href="#appeals">APPEALS</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <!--  Top image GTA, there is no text so it can be <img> tag -->
    <div id="home-img" style="position: relative; z-index: 2;">
      <section id="carouselSection" class="home carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x700" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x700" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x700" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  
    <!--  About us section, with car in background -->
    <div id="about-us" style="position: relative; z-index: 3;">
        <!--  Your regular columns and content -->
        <div class="container-md">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div id="about-title" class="col-4 about-text-header"> 
              <span style="text-decoration: none;">Who are we?</span> 
              <div class="row" class="">
                <button id="learn-more-btn" type="button" class="btn  mx-4 m-3">
                       <img id="redirect-symbol" src="img/redirect.png" class="text-center" alt="" width="30" height="30" style="padding-right: 5px;">
                       <span class="text-center" style="text-decoration: none;">Learn More</span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="about-text" class="col-4 text-wrap">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil tempore cumque cupiditate alias nostrum ad beatae neque mollitia. Molestiae blanditiis voluptatum necessitatibus dolore omnis iure tenetur repellendus quis consequatur magni.
                  <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum quo, ducimus tempore sit mollitia reprehenderit.
                </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="why-us">
      <div class="row">
        <p id="why" class="h1">With so much competition out there why us?</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="memberCount">
      <div class="container-sm">
        <div style="color: white;" class="row align-items-center justify-content-center py-xxl-5">
          <div class="col-4 p-xxl-5">
            <h1>50+</h1>
            <h3>Member Count</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 p-xxl-5">
            <h1>6</h1>
            <h3>Divisions</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 p-xxl-5">
            <h1>30+</h1>
            <h3>Average Patrol Count</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="gallery" class="">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row float-lg-start" style="padding-right: 5rem; padding-top: 5rem;">
            <div class="col-sm mx-5">
              <h2 id="gallery-title" class="">Check out our <br>
                Gallery
              </h2>
          
              <p id="gallery-comment" class="lead">Here is some of the best <br>
                screenshots this month!
              </p>

              <button id="" type="button" class="btn m-3 gallery-button">
                <img id="redirect-symbol" src="img/redirect.png" class="text-center gallery-redirect" alt="" style="padding-right: 5px;">
                <span class="text-center" style="text-decoration: none;">Learn More</span>
              </button>

              <button id="" type="button" class="btn m-3 gallery-button">
                <span class="text-center" style="text-decoration: none;"><i class="fa-brands fa-square-twitter fa-xl" style="padding-right: 1rem;"></i>Follow us</span>
              </button>   

            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top: 5rem;">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x250" style = "padding-right: 1rem;" class="rounded mx-auto d-block float-sm-start img-thumbnail" alt="...">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x250" style = "padding-right: 1rem;" class="rounded mx-auto d-block float-sm-start img-thumbnail" alt="...">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x250" style = "padding-right: 1rem;" class="rounded mx-auto d-block float-sm-start img-thumbnail" alt="...">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x250" style = "padding-right: 1rem;" class="rounded mx-auto d-block float-sm-start img-thumbnail" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="contact" class="">
      <div class="container-sm">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div id="contact-statement" class="col-4 about-text-header" style=""> 
            <span class="" style="text-decoration: none;;">If you like what you</span> <span id="contact-statement-left"><br>see then apply!</span> 
          </div>
          <div id="contact-final" class="col-4 text-wrap">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil tempore cumque cupiditate alias nostrum ad beatae neque mollitia. Molestiae blanditiis voluptatum necessitatibus dolore omnis iure tenetur repellendus quis consequatur magni.
              <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum quo, ducimus tempore sit mollitia reprehenderit.
            </p>
            <button id="contact-button" type="button" class="btn m-3 gallery-button justify-content-center">
              <img id="redirect-symbol" src="img/redirect.png" class="text-center" alt="" width="25" height="25" style="padding-right: 5px;">
              <span class="text-center" style="text-decoration: none;">Apply now!</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-2  pt-5">
            <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced">
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-1 mb-5 pt-5">
            <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced">
              <li class="mb-2"><h6 class="text-uppercase">Headers</h6></li>
              <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Feed</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Divisions</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Updates</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 pt-5">
            <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced">
              <li class="mb-2"><h6 class="text-uppercase">Application</h6></li>
              <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced">
                <li><a href="">Apply</a></li>
                <li><a href="">FMS Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Appeal</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Recruitment</a></li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 pt-5">
            <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced">
              <li class="mb-2"><h6 class="text-uppercase">Social Media</h6></li>
              <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced">
                <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Youtube</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Discord</a></li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```